# Jasper Report in Excel format conversion

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am currently working in JasperReports. I have one method to generate report in PDF format. It is working fine but I want the same report in excel format.

Here is my method:

```
public void generateFleetReportPdf(List<DailyTrakingReportBean> listOfDailyBean) throws JRException, IOException {
    /*
     Convert List to JRBeanCollectionDataSource 
     */
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listOfDailyBean);

    /* 
        Map to hold Jasper Report parameters
    */

    Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("ItemDataSource", beanCollectionDataSource);

    String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/reports/sadaqatReport.jasper");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, parameters, beanCollectionDataSource);
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code. It should export the Jasper report to **.xlsx** format. If you prefer **.xls**, then replace `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRXlsxExporter` with `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter`

```
public void generateFleetReportXlsx(List listOfDailyBean) throws JRException, IOException {
    /*
     Convert List to JRBeanCollectionDataSource 
     */
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listOfDailyBean);

    /* 
        Map to hold Jasper Report parameters
    */

    Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("ItemDataSource", beanCollectionDataSource);

    String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/reports/sadaqatReport.jasper");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, parameters, beanCollectionDataSource);
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xlsx");
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRXlsxExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRXlsxExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,outputStream);
    exporter.exportReport();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: I am trying. wait please.

Comment: This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Have you set the correct Content-Type in header? Also, please try flushing and closing the outputStream before returning. `outputStream.flush();outputStream.close();`

Comment: I've updated my post to set content type and close the output stream. Please try with it.

Comment: Its again showing me this error and the other problem is that file extension is report.xlsx-1.xht why .xht is showing?

Comment: Its working fine. Jaganathan Nanthakumar you are great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
        InputStream jasperStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("yourReportName.jasper");
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);

        JRXlsxExporter xlsxExporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        xlsxExporter.exportReport();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=anyName" + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".xlsx");
        response.getOutputStream().write(os.toByteArray());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

    }
    return "success";
}
```